# Java Nested filter and Nested Streams

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

```
class Item {
  int id;
  List<PriceDetails> priceDetails;
  String itemName;
}
```

---

```
class PriceDetails {
  int price;
}
```

I am getting multiple items in a JSON file. I am trying to filter `priceDetails` with empty price (not the items, just removing all the `priceDetails` in the list with empty price)

I am able to write Java code and its working as expected, but I don't know how to write using Java Streams. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Java Code :

```
public static List<Item>  filterByEmptyPrice(List<Item> items) {
    List<Item> result= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++) {
        List<PriceDetails> temp= new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j=0;j<items.get(i).PriceDetails.size();j++) {
            if(nonNull(items.get(i).PriceDetails) && nonNull(items.get(i).priceDetails.get(j).priceDetails.price)) {
                temp.add(items.get(i).priceDetails.get(j));
            }
        }
        items.get(i).priceDetails= temp;
        result.add(items.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In the future, post complete code. This include methods in the class. If you want people to help you, the LEAST you can do is minimize the work THEY have to do to figure out what is wrong with YOUR code.

Comment: `items.get(i).ticketTypes = temp;` - First advice: don't access fields on the object directly, like in this statement (you might be accustomed to that if you're mainly doing JavaScript, but it's not a good practice in Java). Use getters and setters instead. In regard to your question, since you need to **mutate** your objects (*line at the beginning of the comment*) this task isn't suitable to be implemented with streams.

Comment: To echo what Alexander Ivanchenko stated, mutating your collection is something you should not do using streams. *HOWEVER*, if you were to make a defensive copy of your list (clone it), you could flatten it, filter it... In your case, you could map a new list that does not contain `PriceDetails` that meet a certain criteria. You could sum up the prices, and many other operations.

Comment: My last comment was a little confusing. I was trying to convey two ideas. 1) If you need to mutate your collection, perhaps you should create a copy of the original collection first AND THEN mutate the copy. There are many benefits to this approach, one of which is concurrency and thread safety. 2) The other idea I was trying convey was to Ivan's point: Streams should be used to filter, flatten, etc. You can also collect results, such as summing the prices in the list. You should read about the functions the Stream API provides to have a better idea what it is suitable to do with it.

Comment: Your filterByEmptyTicketPrice() method implementation isn't consistent with the model you specified and doesn't compile.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Scott Its working with the model. Can you elaborate your question please ?

Comment: @deepan see my an answer below. It really doesn't even compile with the model you gave us.

Comment: @Scott This line "item -> new Item(filterPrices(item.priceDetails)" creates a new item with all other fields as null values. I want all other fields to be same, just want to filter these pricedetails with null price, rest all the fields in the items class should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your `filterByEmptyTicketPrice()` method doesn't compile with the `Item` and `PriceDetails` model you gave.

The correct loop based implementation would be:

```java
    public static List<Item> filterByEmptyTicketPrice(List<Item> items) {
        List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Item item : items) {
            List<PriceDetails> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (PriceDetails priceDetails : item.priceDetails) {
                if (nonNull(priceDetails.price)) {
                    temp.add(priceDetails);
                }
            }
            // bug: you mutate your method input here
            item.priceDetails = temp;
            result.add(item);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Also, as noted above, you're mutating the input `items`. The correct way to do this with streams and without mutating the input would be:

```java
    public static List<Item> filterByEmptyTicketPrice(List<Item> items) {
        return items.stream()
                .map(item -> new Item(filterPrices(item.priceDetails)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static List<PriceDetails> filterPrices(List<PriceDetails> priceDetailsList) {
        return priceDetailsList
                .stream()
                .filter(priceDetails -> priceDetails.price != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

This example assumes you've added a new `Item` constructor such as:

```java
public Item(List<PriceDetails> priceDetails) {
    this.priceDetails = priceDetails;
}
```

As others mentioned, you should update the model to use getters to access `priceDetails` and `price` making them private in your `Item` and `PriceDetails` classes.

Comment: This line "item -> new Item(filterPrices(item.priceDetails)" creates a new item with all other fields as null values. I want all other fields to be same, just want to filter these pricedetails with null price, rest all the fields in the items class should be the same.

Comment: I wanted to mutate, just beacuse i just wanted to filter pricedetails in that items. @Scott